spring process-aot plugin goal fails when running in github action due to my file appender
I'm trying to build a web application and compile it to a native image using github actions. My web application needs to log messages in a file when deployed somewhere and for that I have configured a file appender in logback. When running the build in github actions and when the spring boot maven plugin's process-aot goal is running the goal fails with an error saying that log file /app/logs/app.log cannot be created as the directory doesn't exists. I've configured the path using the spring boot property logging.file.name Below is my relevant setup.
Logback-spring.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

<!--    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />-->

    <springProfile name="!local">
        <springProperty name="LOG_FILE" source="logging.file.name"/>
        <springProperty name="SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME" source="spring.application.name"/>
        <springProperty name="SPRING_PROFILES" source="spring.profiles.active"/>
        <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    </springProfile>

    <property name="LOG_CORRELATION_PATTERN" value="[%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}] "/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
<!--    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />-->

    <springProfile name="!local">
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>${FILE_LOG_THRESHOLD}</level>
            </filter>
            <encoder class="co.elastic.logging.logback.EcsEncoder">
                <serviceName>${SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME}</serviceName>
                <serviceEnvironment>${SPRING_PROFILES}</serviceEnvironment>
                <stackTraceAsArray>true</stackTraceAsArray>
            </encoder>
            <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_FILE_NAME_PATTERN:-${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz}</fileNamePattern>
                <cleanHistoryOnStart>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_CLEAN_HISTORY_ON_START:-false}</cleanHistoryOnStart>
                <maxFileSize>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_MAX_FILE_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
                <totalSizeCap>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-0}</totalSizeCap>
                <maxHistory>${LOGBACK_ROLLINGPOLICY_MAX_HISTORY:-7}</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
    </springProfile>


    <springProfile name="!local">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="local">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>

**github actions step **
      - name: Test with Maven
        if: github.ref_type == 'branch' && !(startsWith(github.ref_name, 'release') || startsWith(github.ref_name, 'main'))
        run: mvn -Pnative -Dspring-boot.aot.jvmArguments="-Dspring.main.cloud-platform=kubernetes" -Ddocker.publishRegistry.url=${{ env.REGISTRY }} -Ddocker.publishRegistry.username=${{ github.actor }} -Ddocker.publishRegistry.password=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.ref_name }} --batch-mode --update-snapshots --show-version package
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

error
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:another-boot-logback.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for [/app/logs/app.log]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/app/logs/app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/logs/app.log (No such file or directory)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at com.fantasy.football.web.api.FantasyFootballWebApplication.main(FantasyFootballWebApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.lambda$prepareApplicationContext$0(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor$AotProcessorHook.run(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.prepareApplicationContext(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/logs/app.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:289)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:230)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:206)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:126)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:104)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.postHandle(AppenderModelHandler.java:84)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:257)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator.processModel(SpringBootJoranConfigurator.java:122)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:287)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.lambda$loadConfiguration$1(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:249)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.withLoggingSuppressed(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:467)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:244)
        ... 36 more

These are some details that I thought was relevant to the problem I can share more though if something else is required. I would need some direction on how to proceed to make this build successful using github actions.
Thanks in advance.
